# how to import/export dll and use its function

Tags: dllimport, 7zip, compression

I am developing a project. I want to include a particular function from 7zip software to decompress data. Its a kinda exporting a particular function from 7zip software to my project. Should I do using DLL import and export or is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should take a look in [LZMA SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html), it would give access to 7zip function from C++/C#/C/Java.

Comment: tanx 4 ur reply,but my question is how do i include a PARTICULAR function from 7zip to my Program

Comment: I think if they provide a SDK is to avoid to have a DLL, I don't see what difference it would make to have access to the full blow 7z instead of one function. your executable need to be compact ?

Comment: Alrite,let me pharse it clearly of what am doing...
In 7zip v have lots of option in that compress/decompress are one of them.....
I need the decompress function alone to be used in my project
i cant goahead and write the entire decompress in my project since it has so many def's and header files..its totally complicated..
instead of doing that i need to call that function(Decompress) from
my program to perform its action..

Comment: If you want a quick and dirty solution why don't you put 7z binary in your project and use exec to make 7z binary do the job

Comment: unfortunately its not my desire friend...tnx alot 4 ur replies..
if there are any other way..let me know